# Group by on string Array in List of items c#

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a `List` of `BlogPageModel` , in `List` I have string Array of Category.

Model class looks like below:

```
    public class BlogPageModel : BaseModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string[] Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I want list of all Category with blogs count as output, i.e

```
Travel-20
Entertainment-5
```

Note: Travel-20 mean 20 blogs are in list which have Travel Category, and Entertainment-5 mean 5 blogs are Entertainment category, remember few blogs have both categories.

I tried to apply `GroupBy` like below:

```
_client.GetRecords().Result.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => new { Key = x.Key })
```

But it's not working and returning list of blogs.

I also tried below:

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my query.

Comment: Does `Travel-20` mean that 20 `BlogPageModel`'s in your list have the string "Travel" in the `Category` array?

Comment: Yes Travel-20 mean 20 blogs are in list which have Travel Category, and Entertainment-5 mean 5 blogs are Entertainment category, remember few blogs have both categories.

Comment: I don't have `C#` to test right now, but I think there is some sort of `Count()` or similar method to put after `Select()`

Comment: `Category` should be called `Categories`. Collections should have a plural name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly flatten the result using `SelectMany`. You should use `GroupBy` Again to grouping the tags by key and finally count them like this:

```
var result = _client.GetRecords().Result
                .SelectMany(x => x.Category)
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => $"{x.Key}-{x.Count()}");
```

Comment: Please add some more words than just "try this". Answers on SO should not promote "coding by trial and error"

Comment: Surely the first groupby is a wasted operation then?

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the blogs with their list of categories to a new sequence of just the category, before you group it:

```
_client.GetRecords().Result.SelectMany(blog => blog.Category).GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => x.Key + "-" + x.Count());
```

x is an IGrouping, basically like a List together with a Key. You can do things on it that you would do on a List, like Count or First. Every item in the list has a common Key, which was chosen as part of the GroupBy. In this case your x where the key is "Travel" is a list of Category 20 long

Incidentally, (assuming GetRecords returns a Task) consider whether you should be using `.Result` - it blocks the calling thread until the operation is finished which is a great way to nuke all the advantages of task based Async pattern and revert to synchronous code. If you instead `await` GetRecords (which should be called GetRecordsAsync) then it will free the thread up to go and do other things while the records are being returned

```
(await _client.GetRecords()).SelectMany(blog => blog.Category).GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => x.Key + "-" + x.Count());
```

If you want to keep the Blog object after the SelectMany has ended you can use:

```
(await _client.GetRecords()).SelectMany(b => blog.Category, (b, c) => new { Blog = blog, Cat = c })
```

You'll get an enumerable that has Nblogs * Ncategories (25 items)

Comment: not worked, its not returning correct output, you can see the image in my question, I post there